# Is there any performance benefit to minifying MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I recently ran across some tools that help you minify queries, and I'm curious to know if that's actually something that could help performance.

Comment: Performance of what exactly? Will the "minified" (whatever that means) complete execution faster?

Comment: By minifying you mean to remove all extra symbols and make query text unreadable? )

Comment: @mustaccio correct

Comment: @Nikita Yes, removing all extra unnecessary characters so it's has the least amount of characters in it as possible while still being machine-readable all the same.

Comment: Why do you think it would execute faster?

Comment: @mustaccio I find myself skeptical that this is something that people who are minifying their queries are actually benefitting from. Perhaps they're doing it for another reason. I thought I would ask the community to see if anyone might be able to provide any credibility towards this practice.

Comment: I'd like to see an example of a minimized SQL statement. Much of it is either keywords or SQL identifiers, none of which you can minify, which leaves just some of whitespace, and may be correlation names if used. So this "minification" will be pretty much superficial.

Comment: [This one](https://wtools.io/sql-minifier) is quite funny. It replaces a newline (0x0a) with a space (0x20) and calls it a minified statement. It tells you everything you need to know about the practice.

Comment: @mustaccio That tool claims it helps with "removing all whitespace, indentation and newlines for decreased size and amount of data transferred to clients. The purpose of minification is to increase the speed of communication between servers. Minimization can make a query up to 10% smaller, resulting in a faster download time."

So I guess the theory is passing a shorter query from a program gets it over to MySQL faster?

Comment: Well, if you're sending it to a rover on Mars, few bytes might make a difference. On a 1 Gb network, hardly.

Comment: @mustaccio Clearly. So unless some bright mind with some deep dive knowledge of how MySQL (or even possibly other databases that could add to the conversation) process the query it's given can give me a reason of how minifying queries can speed up something, I really don't think it's worth doing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to post an answer just to put an end to this bizarre debate.

TLDR: No, "minification" will not provide any performance benefit that you would notice.

"Minification" refers to a process of removing any optional whitespace from a program source code and giving program identifiers (variables, functions, etc.) shortest possible names, all while retaining the original semantics of the program. The original purpose of it was to reduce the download time of JavaScript code embedded in (or linked from) HTML pages, with the aim of improving user experience on many web sites. As a side effect, minified JavaScript code is practically unreadable by humans, which brought about the secondary usage of the practice, that of obfuscating the source code, often for malicious purposes.

SQL statement syntax differs from other programming languages in that it rarely has any variables<sup>1</sup>; it contains mostly keywords and SQL object identifiers, which obviously cannot be replaced by arbitrary shorter tokens without stripping a statement entirely of its meaning. That leaves only two minification targets: optional whitespace and, possibly, correlation names when such are used, which makes minification "improvement", in terms of the overall statement length, significantly less impressive.

Further, unlike transferring sources of HTML pages over long range internet links from web servers to residential clients, the part of the overall SQL statement processing cycle that can be theoretically improved by reducing the length of the statement string is negligible, compared to other steps, such as optimizing the statement, executing it, and sending statement results back to the client, if applicable. Besides, SQL statements normally travel over backbone networks, which are much faster and experience much less contention than public internet.

Finally, if you decide to apply minification to dynamically composed SQL statements, you might even see overall performance *degradation*, because a poorly written minification code<sup>2</sup> will probably have overhead that  outweighs whatever "benefits" it produces.

As a result, you<sup>3</sup> are unlikely to perceive *any* difference in effective statement processing time (from submission to receiving first results) between minified and non-minified statements.

---

1 - PSM and compound SQL statement code can, of course, contain variable names, but in the cases when such code is used, potential network throughput improvements from minification are even less significant.
2 - I would find it doubtful that people engaging in such practice can produce high quality code.
3 - Yes, even if you are developing a High Frequency Trading application.